# Finding a regular expression of a language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Our alphabet is {a,b} and we need to find a regular expression for the language of all words of the form $a^*b^*$, whose length is a multiple of 3.

Obviously $(aaa)^*(bbb)^*$ is one of the options, but I just can't formalize more options.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "aabbbb" for example. The length is 6 (divisible by 3) but this is not of the form $(aaa)^*(bbb)^*$

Comment: "bbbaaa" is just another obvious form like I noted above. But what about other forms? How can I formalize them?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your triplets, and use Kleene star: $$(aaa)^*(bbb)^*$$

Now, add cases where number of $a$ is not divisible by 3, say aabbbb, as alternative.
$$ (aaa)^*(bbb)^* + (aaa)^*aab(bbb)^* + (aaa)^*abb(bbb)^*$$

Comment: these are not of the form $a^*b^*$.

Comment: So, can I just take out the wrong ones from his answer? 
Does
$((aaa)∪(aab)∪(abb)∪(bbb))^*$
cover all the options?

Comment: @RanG. Thank you. Sorry, I for unknown reason understood the length must be divisible by 3. Asher, no for the same reason you cannot use alternative, my bad.

Comment: Yes, I just realized I was wrong too

Comment: So how about:
$((aaa)^*+(bbb)^*)^*+((aaa)^*abb(bbb)^*)+((aaa)^*aab(bbb)^*)$
? Does this cover all the cases, including the case of $(aaa)^*(bbb)^*$ ?

Comment: Almost, the first one should not be under Kleene, because you could produce bbbaaa, it should be ((aaa)*(bbb)*), and it would be proper.